# Read csv data with D3.csv, each column in separate array

Tags: html, csv, d3.js

I'm new to working D3.js and html/js in general and I'm trying to figure out how to read in a csv file into separate arrays using d3.csv. I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
cause, prevalence, disability;
cancer, .3, .4;
aids, .5, .5;
malaria, .2, .1;
```

For now, I'm struggling with creating arrays for "cause", "prevalence", and "disability.  Here is the code that I am using:

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.csv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    d3.csv('disability.csv', function(csv){
      var cause=csv[0];
      var prevalence=csv[1];
      var disability=csv[2];
      for (i=0;i<cause.length;i++)
      {
        document.write(cause[i] + "<br />");
      }
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

The `document.write` portion is simply to test that I have read in the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you mean `var cause = csv[0]` to refer to the first variable/column, I'm guessing? Without seeing the csv file it's hard to know for sure.

If that's the case, the reason it's not working is javascript arrays unfortunately don't have easy ways of accessing a single variable/column.

`csv[0]` instead refers to the first *row* of your csv. In the case of d3's csv module, it'll be a dictionary with keys for each variable (column name) in the csv, e.g.:

```
console.log(csv[0]);
{ cause: 'A', prevalence: .1, disability: .5 }
```

So if you want to create separate arrays for each variable/column, you could do something like this:

```
var cause = [],
    prevalence = [],
    disability = [];
csv.map(function(d) {
    cause.push(d.cause);
    prevalence.push(d.prevalence);
    disability.push(d.disability);
}
```

Then you'd be left with the three arrays it looks like you're trying to make. But in d3 you can probably actually just pass the entire `csv` object as the `data` to whatever you're creating and then use an accessor function [e.g. `.attr('y', function(d) { return d.prevalence; })`] to use a specific column/variable in a particular context.