# Can I normalise CSV data with D3?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have this sort of data in my original CSV:

```
id, lat, long, data_type_1, data_type_2, data_type_3
1 , 50,  1,    10,          20,          40
```

And I need to transform it to this kind of structure:

```
id, lat, long, data_type, value,
1 , 50,  1,    1,          10,
1 , 50,  1,    2,          20,
1 , 50,  1,    3,          40,
```

I've looked at the devdocs for [d3.csv](http://devdocs.io/d3~4/d3-request#csv) and a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7999971/1075247) or two.

I've got this code, pinched/modified from this [bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8fe6fa6ed1fa976e5dd76cfa4d816fec) page.

```
d3.csv("traffic_data.csv", function(d) {
                numericColHeaders.forEach(header => d[header] = parseInt(d[height]));
                console.error(d); // to inspect in the console
                return d;
            }, function(error, data) {
                if (error) throw error;
                var root = d3.stratify()
                    .id(function(d) {
                        return d.data_type;
                    })
                    .parentId(function(d) {
                        return d.id;
                    })
                    (data)
                    .sum(function(d) {
                        return d.value;
                    })
                    .sort(function(a, b) {
                        return b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value;
                    });

                treemap(root);
                // do more stuff
            })
```

When I've console'd out the data, it prints a row, but to get to my data normalised I need to 'expand' this into multiple rows, and I can't get my head round how to do this. I can't think of how to do this with `map`, `filter` or `reduce`.... If anything I want the opposite of reduce.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to convert each record in your CSV into 3 records (one for each data_type.  You want to `push()` them into a new data array and use that in your visualization

Comment: @genestd in the csv function or the callback? If it's in the csv function I'll end up with nested arrays...

Comment: Do it in the callback, and then pass the new variable into your `stratify()` function as `(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without D3 using the builtin `map` and `reduce` functions like so:

```
rows.map(row => {
  const { id, lat, long, data_type_1, data_type_2, data_type_3 } = row

  return [
    {
      id, lat, long,
      data_type: '1',
      value: data_type_1
    },
    {
      id, lat, long,
      data_type: '2',
      value: data_type_2
    },
    {
      id, lat, long,
      data_type: '3',
      value: data_type_3
    }
  ]
}).reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next), [])
```

`long` being a reserved word, this code won't completely work. But should give you the right idea.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't include any code to parse the csv. It expects it to already be parsed into a list of objects where the keys are the column headers